# IOS catch all crash scenarios

Tags: ios, crash

How do I put some exception handling code in my app so that whatever strange crash that happens, the app would detect it and do something like restarting the app?

Comment: I agree with Dominik. While debugging the app, though, you can use [exception breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), which can be incredibly helpful.

Comment: Integrate [plcrashreporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) into your app to make it easier to get crash report from your users.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible since most crashes occur because of some memory fault or other things your app can not recover from. You also can not tell iOS to restart your app.

The best thing is, obviously, to prevent crashes from happening all together. There are helpful tools that collect crash reports for you like [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com) or [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net). [This article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) will help you to understand those logs even better.